# How can I get my Tumblr theme to separate tags with commas?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

At the end of every post type in my Tumblr theme, I've got this code:

```
<p class="permalink">
   <a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>
   {block:HasTags} &nbsp;&nbsp; # filed under:
      {block:Tags}  
         <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
      {/block:Tags}
   {/block:HasTags}
</p>
```

(I know the `&nbsp;` bit is not exactly a class act. It was my four second workaround, and it's not the purpose of this question, so bear with me!)

On a post with multiple tags, that yields:

[image: this is what it looks like]

If I just add a comma after `{Tag}`, making it `<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag},</a>`, I get:

[image: too many commas]

The last tag has an extraneous comma, and posts with only one tag would show the extra comma under this method, as well.

How do I add just the right number of commas?

---

**Update**:

Jeremy's answer below did what I wanted. But, in an attempt to <strike>get fancy</strike> be "standards-compliant" (though I don't know why anyone using IE8 would read my tumblr), I attempted to implement w3d's suggestion. So now the CSS looks like:

```
a.tag:before {
  content:", ";
}
a.tag:first-child:before {
  content:"";
}
```

The result is now:

[image: updated screenshot]

(*n.b.: the line break is unrelated - I added that on purpose.*)

So. What went wrong?

Comment: It's not really a case of _being_ "standards compliant", it's just that IE8 will only support this CSS if it is in standards compliant mode. Unfortunately all users on Windows XP will be limited to IE8 since you need Vista+ to upgrade to IE9.

Comment: @w3d Hm. Noted. Shoulda kept it at 'getting fancy'! :)

Comment: Sorry, I feel as if I'm messing things up, since it was obviously working OK for you in your browser. The additional white-space after the tag and before the `,` is probably the white-space that occurs after the `</a>` in your markup/theme. You could try removing this. The first comma is still present? Try changing `content:"";` to `content:"%";` just to see if `%` shows? (Although I see from your comment on my answer that this may not have any effect?!)

Comment: Which browser(s) are you trying this in?

Comment: @w3d, the % doesn't show up. I'm running Chrome 13.0.782.220 on OS X Lion. Will go back to Jeremy's solution for now but continue to tweak. No worries about messing it up - it's a fun problem to chew on!

Comment: This is how it should look: http://jsfiddle.net/w3dx/sM66G/ - at least this works OK for me in Chrome 13.0.782.220 on _Windows_. I wonder if this is a browser bug?! I encountered something very similar in Chrome 10 on Windows where `first-child:before` was not actioned unless `first-child` was previously defined. This was, however, fixed by Chrome 12 on Windows at least. Try this updated fiddle which includes this fix: http://jsfiddle.net/w3dx/sM66G/1/

Comment: @w3d That doesn't appear to have changed a thing. I think it sounds browser buggy too... except I just saved those changes and pulled up my tumblr in Safari 5.1. Still no dice.

Comment: Are you saying that neither of those examples display OK for you in either Chrome or Safari on OS X?!

Comment: Still, you run into the problem of the comma in a before content property being added _inside_ the styling for the tag. If you aren't underlining the anchor tag, then I guess it's no big deal. Silly IE. You could just insert a fix for IE in JS....

Comment: @Jeremy - I did notice that when I decided to play with separating | tags | like | this instead, of, like, this.

Comment: I guess it would be more usual to apply the `first-child`/`last-child:before` thing to a containing element, like an `li` rather than the anchor. Then the `, ` would be part of the `li` and not affect the anchor. But I like @jeremy's 2nd answer though.

Comment: Well, you'd still need to contain the `a` tag within something else and use that something else with the `:before` property so that it doesn't get styled like a link.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I got hold of a screenshot of my [first fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3dx/sM66G/) on Safari 5.0 / OS X (curtesy of Adobe BrowserLabs) and this appears to look correct - no preceeding comma before the first tag. (Screenshot added to my answer below.) May be there are other conflicting styles in the stylesheet; although I can't imagine what?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got another idea.

```
{block:Tags}<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a><span class="tagtail"></span>{/block:Tags}
```

This will add a *span* with the "tagtail" class after every tag.

Then, add this css:

```
span.tagtail + a.tag:before {
   content:", ";
}
```

This will select every *tag* anchor that comes after a *tagtail* span (so every one but the first). This way, we avoid the need to use the *first-child* or *last-child* selectors.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to ensure that the commas are styled apart from the anchor, I suppose you could also do:

```
{block:Tags}<span class="taghead">, </span><a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}
```

and then style it like:

```
span.taghead { display:none; }
a.tag + span.taghead { display:inline; }
```

However, this might need tweaking because browsers differ on overriding rules.

Comment: +1 ... A shame about the extra markup, but I like it! :)

Comment: I've found myself throwing extra unnecessary markup in a lot of design to get IE to match layout with CSS it doesn't support.

Comment: If you want to ensure that the commas are styled apart from the anchor, I suppose you could also do: `{block:Tags}<span class="taghead">, </span><a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}` and then style it like: `span.taghead { display:none; } a.tag + span.taghead { display:inline; }`. However, this might need tweaking because browsers differ on overriding rules.

Comment: @Jeremy, this last bit is working *perfectly*. The `tagtail` method was rendering a space before the comma, but this little `taghead` bit is making me very happy now. Consider adding your comment back into the answer?

Comment: Done and done! Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Try some CSS trickery (to get it to work in IE 8, you need to specify a <!DOCTYPE> at the top of the document).

```
<p class="permalink">
       <a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>
       {block:HasTags} &nbsp;&nbsp; # filed under:
          {block:Tags}  
             <a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
          {/block:Tags}
       {/block:HasTags}
</p>
```

Then, add the following CSS:

```
a.tag:after {
   content:",";
}

a.tag:last-child:after {
   content:"";
}
```

It uses the pseudo-selector *:after* and the little-used *content* property to add the comma after the fact. The second rule overrides the content property for the last tag in the sequence.

Comment: Excellent. Huge success. Thanks, Jeremy!

Comment: @Jeremy: IE8 does not support the `last-child` pseudo-class even in standards compliant mode (ie. with a DOCTYPE). You will need to use `first-child:before` in order to support IE8 (and IE7).

Comment: @w3d: That sucks. Silly IE. I'm not sure why your first-child:before selector isn't working properly for Abby, but I've added another answer with another idea that adds spans and uses the + selector.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from @Jeremy's answer... To support IE8 (and IE7) you will need to use the `first-child` pseudo-class, rather than `last-child`. IE8 does not support `last-child`, even in standards compliant mode (ie. with a DOCTYPE).

```
a.tag:before {
   content:", ";    /* comma + space */
}

a.tag:first-child:before {
   content:"";
}
```

**EDIT:** However, a slight caveat with this approach is that you will probably have to remove any additional white-space that appears after the closing `</a>` in your markup/theme.

```
      {block:Tags}<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}
```

**EDIT:** Screenshot of output of [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3dx/sM66G/) in Safari 5.0 on OS X:

[image: Screenshot of output of fiddle in Safari 5.0 on OS X]

Comment: I am using `a.tag:before {  content:", ";}` and `a.tag:first-child:before {  content:"# tagged: ";}`, but it results in a row of tags that just says `, Mareen Fischinger , New York City , Times Square`. Hm. This comment is confusing. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the `:before` suggestion in previous answers.  If you are working with a list of tags it's quite possible that you will be placing them in a list.  If you do use each `li` tag with `:before` rather than the a tag inside the `li` tag - each tag will be the first-child of the `li` tag however only one `li` tag will be the first-child of the `ul` or `ol` tag! I am using a description list as I wanted to put "Tags" in the `d`t tag so the same applies to the `d`d tag.

Using a description list however has an added complexity however.  The first `dd` tag is never the first-child of the `dl` tag, it's the `dt` tag, so you need to use `nth-child(2)` to target it.  The downside of using `nth-child(2)` is that again it's not IE 8 compliant so that issue comes around again.

Here's my solution.

```
{block:HasTags}
<div class="t">
<dl>
<dt>Tags</dt>
{block:Tags}
<dd><a href="{TagURL}" class="tag">{Tag}</a></dd>
{/block:Tags}
</dl>
</div>
{/block:HasTags}
```

Also from previous answers they suggest that using a space in content (`content: ", ";`) works.  Does it work?  I can't get it to work but "\00a0" will.

```
.t dl {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.t dt {
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
}
.t dd {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
}

.t dd:before {
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    content: ",\00a0";
    float: left;
}

.t dd:nth-child(2):before {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    content: "";
    float: left;
}
```