# How can I make tags visible using this tumblr theme? 

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I've made several attempts to add tags to my tumblr posts, but each time I try to edit the theme I end up with a list of tags across the top of my blog instead of included in each seperate post.
Can anyone tell me how to edit the theme below to add tags to my posts?

```
<!-- {block:Posts} -->

        <!-- DATES -->

        <!-- {block:NewDayDate} -->
        <div class="entry date">
            <div class="icon">
                <a class="permalink" href="/archive/{Year}/{MonthNumber}"></a>
            </div><!-- /.icon -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p><a href="/archive/{Year}/{MonthNumber}">{Month} {DayOfMonth} {Year}</a></p>
                </div><!-- /.caption -->
            </div><!-- /.content -->
        </div><!-- /.entry .date -->
        <!-- {/block:NewDayDate} -->

        <!-- PHOTO -->
        <!-- {block:Photo} -->
        <div class="post photo" id="p_{PostID}">
            <div class="icon">
                <a class="permalink" href="{Permalink}"></a>
                {block:HighRes}<a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" rel="lightbox" class="zoom"></a>{/block:HighRes}
                {block:IndexPage}
                {block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}" class="notes">*{NoteCount}<br></a>{/block:NoteCount}
                {/block:IndexPage}
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="the_photo">
                    <div class="photo_inner photo_loading">
                    {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" class="faint" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>{LinkCloseTag}
                    </div>
                </div><!-- .the_photo -->
                <!--{block:Caption}-->
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>{Caption}</p>
                    {block:Date}{block:IfDisqusShortname}<p><a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread"></a></p>{block:IfDisqusShortname}{/block:Date}
                </div><!-- /.caption -->
                <!--{/block:Caption}-->
            </div><!-- /.content -->
        </div><!-- /.post .photo -->
```

```
        <!-- VIDEO -->

        <!-- {block:Video} -->
        <div class="post video" id="p_{PostID}">
            <div class="icon">
                <a class="permalink" href="{Permalink}"></a>
                {block:IndexPage}
                {block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}" class="notes">*{NoteCount}<br></a>{/block:NoteCount}
                {/block:IndexPage}
            </div><!-- /.icon -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="player">{Video-500}</div>
                <!--{block:Caption}-->
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>{Caption}</p>
                    {block:Date}{block:IfDisqusShortname}<p><a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread"></a></p>{block:IfDisqusShortname}{/block:Date}
                </div><!-- /.caption -->
                <!--{/block:Caption}-->
            </div><!-- /.content -->
        </div><!-- /.post .video -->
        <!-- {/block:Video} -->

        <!-- LINK -->

        <!-- {block:Link} -->
        <div class="post link" id="p_{PostID}">
            <div class="icon">
                <a class="permalink" href="{Permalink}"></a>
                {block:IndexPage}
                {block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}" class="notes">*{NoteCount}<br></a>{/block:NoteCount}
                {/block:IndexPage}
            </div><!-- /.icon -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3><a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name}</a></h3>
                    <p><span class="description">{Description}</span></p>
                    {block:Date}{block:IfDisqusShortname}<p><a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread"></a></p>{block:IfDisqusShortname}{/block:Date}
                </div><!-- /.caption -->
            </div><!-- /.content -->
        </div><!-- /.post .link -->
        <!-- {/block:Link} -->

        <!-- REGULAR -->

        <!-- {block:Regular} -->
        <div class="post regular" id="p_{PostID}">
            <div class="icon">
                <a class="permalink" href="{Permalink}"></a>
                {block:IndexPage}
                {block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}" class="notes">*{NoteCount}<br></a>{/block:NoteCount}
                {/block:IndexPage}
            </div><!-- /.icon -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                    <p>{Body}</p>
                    {block:Date}{block:IfDisqusShortname}<p><a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread"></a></p>{block:IfDisqusShortname}{/block:Date}
                </div><!-- /.caption -->
            </div><!-- /.content -->
        </div><!-- /.post .regular -->
        <!-- {/block:Regular} -->

        <!-- QUOTE -->

        <!-- {block:Quote} -->
        <div class="post quote" id="p_{PostID}">
            <div class="icon">
                <a class="permalink" href="{Permalink}"></a>
                {block:IndexPage}
                {block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}" class="notes">*{NoteCount}<br></a>{/block:NoteCount}
                {/block:IndexPage}
            </div><!-- /.icon -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p class="the_quote {Length}"><span class="quote_mark">"</span>{Quote}<span class="quote_mark">"</span></p>
                    <!-- {block:Source} -->
                    <p class="source">{Source}</p>
                    <!-- {/block:Source} -->
                    {block:Date}{block:IfDisqusShortname}<p><a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread"></a></p>{block:IfDisqusShortname}{/block:Date}
                </div><!-- /.caption -->
            </div><!-- /.content -->
        </div><!-- /.post .quote -->            
        <!-- {/block:Quote} -->

        <!-- AUDIO -->

        <!-- {block:Audio} -->
        <div class="post audio" id="p_{PostID}">
            <div class="icon">
                <a class="permalink" href="{Permalink}"></a>
                {block:ExternalAudio}<a href="{ExternalAudioURL}" class="download"></a>{/block:ExternalAudio}
                {block:IndexPage}
                {block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}" class="notes">*{NoteCount}<br></a>{/block:NoteCount}
                {/block:IndexPage}
            </div><!-- /.icon -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="the_player">{AudioPlayerGrey}</div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>{Caption}</p>
                    {block:Date}{block:IfDisqusShortname}<p><a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread"></a></p>{block:IfDisqusShortname}{/block:Date}
                </div><!-- /.caption -->
            </div><!-- /.content -->
        </div><!-- /.post .quote -->
        <!-- {/block:Audio} -->

        <!-- CONVERSATION -->

        <!-- {block:Conversation} -->
        <div class="post conversation" id="p_{PostID}">
            <div class="icon">
                <a class="permalink" href="{Permalink}"></a>
                {block:IndexPage}
                {block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}" class="notes">*{NoteCount}<br></a>{/block:NoteCount}
                {/block:IndexPage}
            </div><!-- /.icon -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="caption">
                    <!-- {block:Title} -->
                    <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                    <!-- {/block:Title} -->
                    <p>
                        <ul>
                            <!-- {block:Lines} -->
                                <li>
                                    {block:Label}<span class="label {Alt}">{Label}</span>{/block:Label}
                                    {Line}
                                </li>
                                <!-- {/block:Lines} -->
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                    {block:Date}{block:IfDisqusShortname}<p><a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread"></a></p>{block:IfDisqusShortname}{/block:Date}
                </div><!-- /.caption -->
            </div><!-- /.content -->
        </div><!-- /.post .conversation -->
        <!-- {/block:Conversation} --> 


        <!--{block:PermalinkPage}-->
        <!--{block:Date}-->
        <!--{block:PostNotes}-->
        <div class="entry post_notes">
            <div class="icon">
                <a class="permalink" href="{Permalink}"></a>
            </div><!-- /.icon -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="the_notes">
                    {PostNotes}
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.caption -->
            </div><!-- /.content -->
        </div><!-- /.entry .notes -->
        <!--{/block:PostNotes}-->

        <!--{block:IfDisqusShortname}-->
        <div class="entry">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="caption">
                    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/{text:Disqus Shortname}/embed.js"></script>
                    <noscript><a href="http://{text:Disqus Shortname}.disqus.com/?url=ref">{lang:View the discussion thread}</a></noscript>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--{/block:IfDisqusShortname}-->
        <!--{/block:Date}-->
        <!--{/block:PermalinkPage}-->           


        <!-- {/block:Posts} -->
```

Comment: Why are all of your `{block:}`s commented out?

Answer (score 2):

Include the following code:

```
{block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
       <a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
```

in the block for *each type of post*. So you will have this seven times: in `{block:Text}`, in `{block:Audio}`, etc.

Put this right before the closing of the block (so right before `{/block:Text}`, for example) to have the tags show up at the end of the post.

Tumblr provides some documentation on this [here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#tags).

Comment: There's a lot of good information on playing with tumblr tags in [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18790/how-can-i-get-my-tumblr-theme-to-separate-tags-with-commas).

Comment: [This question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18104/tumblr-tags-are-showing-below-the-posts-instead-of-inside-the-box), also useful.