# Tumblr Theme HTML - Want Tags Below Post

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

So here's my problem. I got my hands on a premade Tumblr theme, but it didn't quite have everything I wanted, so I went to the web and found instructions piece-by-piece to add what I wanted. One thing that I wanted was my tags to show up beneath my post.

I originally put my HasTags block at the very end of the Posts block, but my tags for the entire page were showing up at the top of the page. After a little more research, I eventually put HasTags blocks at the end of every individual post-type block. This put my tags with my posts, but they mostly show up before captions and sources.

I would like the tags to show up below everything, like most other blogs.

```
{block:Posts}
            <div id="post" 
                {block:Video}class="video"{/block:Video}
                {block:Photoset}class="photoset"{/block:Photoset}>
            <div id="background"></div>    

        {block:Text}
              {block:Title}
                  <a href="{Permalink}"><h3>{Title}</h3></a>
              {/block:Title}
              {Body}
              <br> {block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
       #<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
        {/block:Text}

        {block:Photo}
            <div id="photo">
                {block:IndexPage}
                {Block:IfNotSwitchPhotoPostHoverStyle}
                <a href="{Permalink}"><div id="gradient"></div></a>
                {block:Date}
                <div id="hover"><div id="background"></div>  
                  {block:NoteCount}
                  <a href="{Permalink}" class="N">{NoteCount}</a> 
                  {/block:NoteCount}
                  <a href="{Permalink}" class="T">
                  {DayOfMonthWithZero}.{MonthNumberWithZero}.{ShortYear}
                  </a>
                  <a href="{ReblogURL}" class="R">Reblog</a>  
                </div>
                {/block:Date}
                {/Block:IfNotSwitchPhotoPostHoverStyle}

                {Block:IfSwitchPhotoPostHoverStyle}
                {block:Date}
                <div id="hover"><div id="background"></div>  
                  <div id="links">
                  {block:NoteCount}
                  <a href="{Permalink}" class="N">{NoteCount}</a><br />
                  {/block:NoteCount}
                  <a href="{Permalink}" class="T">
                  {DayOfMonthWithZero}.{MonthNumberWithZero}.{ShortYear}
                  </a>
                  <a href="{ReblogURL}" class="R">Reblog</a> 
                  {block:RebloggedFrom}
                  <a href="{ReblogRootURL}" class="S">Source</a> 
                  {/block:RebloggedFrom}
                  </div>
                </div>
                {/block:Date}
                {/Block:IfSwitchPhotoPostHoverStyle}

                <a href="{Permalink}">
                <img src="{PhotoURL-500}"/></a>
                {/block:IndexPage}

                    {block:PermalinkPage}
                    <center><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"/></center>   
                    {/block:PermalinkPage}
            </div>
           <br> {block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
       #<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
        {/block:Photo}

        {block:Photoset}
                    {block:IndexPage}
                    <center>{Photoset-400}</center> 
                    {/block:IndexPage}

                    {block:PermalinkPage}
                    <center>{Photoset-500}</center>   
                    {/block:PermalinkPage}
                    <br> {block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
       #<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
        {/block:Photoset}

        {block:Quote}
              <div id="quote">
              <div id="quote_symbol">,,</div>
              <a href="{Permalink}"><h3>{Quote}</h3></a>

              {block:Source}
                  <div class="source">{Source}</div>
              {/block:Source}
              </div>
              <br> {block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
       #<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
        {/block:Quote}

        {block:Link}
              <a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}><h3>
              {Name}</h3></a>
              {block:Description}
                  <div class="description">{Description}</div>
              {/block:Description}
              <br> {block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
       #<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
        {/block:Link}

        {block:Audio}
              <div id="audio_box">
              <a href="{Permalink}"><div id="gradient"></div></a>
              <div class="album{block:AlbumArt}art{/block:AlbumArt}">
              {block:AlbumArt}
              {block:IndexPage}<a href="{Permalink}">{/block:IndexPage}
              <img src="{AlbumArtURL}" />
              {block:IndexPage}</a>{/block:IndexPage} 
              {/block:AlbumArt}</div>
              <div id="{postID}" class="audio 
                                {block:AlbumArt}short{/block:AlbumArt}
                                ">
                  {block:IndexPage}
                       {AudioPlayerBlack}
                  {/block:IndexPage}

                  {block:PermalinkPage}
                      {block:ifDarkorlightversion}
                          {AudioPlayerBlack}
                      {/block:ifDarkorlightversion}
                      {block:ifNotDarkorlightversion}
                          {AudioPlayerWhite}
                      {/block:ifNotDarkorlightversion}
                  {/block:PermalinkPage}
              </div>
              {block:PermalinkPage}
              <ul class="artist_info">
                      {block:Artist}
                  <li>{Artist}</li>
                      {/block:Artist}
                      {block:Album}
                  <li>{Album}</li>
                      {/block:Album}
                      {block:TrackName}
                  <li>{TrackName}</li>
                      {/block:TrackName}
              </ul>{/block:PermalinkPage}
              <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
              <br> {block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
       #<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
        {/block:Audio}

        {block:Chat}
              {block:Title}
                  <a href="{Permalink}"><h3>{Title}</h3></a>
              {/block:Title}
              <ul id="chat">
                  {block:Lines}
                      <li class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
                          {block:Label}
                              <span class="label">{Label}</span>
                          {/block:Label}

                          {Line}
                      </li>
                  {/block:Lines}
              </ul>
              <br> {block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
       #<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
        {/block:Chat}

        {block:Video}
           <div id="video">
              <center>{Video-500}</center>
           </div>
           <br> {block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
       #<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
        {/block:Video}

        {block:Answer}
          <div id="question">
              <img src="{AskerPortraitURL-64}" />
              <a href="{Permalink}" title="Got to Permalink page">
              <p><span>{Asker}:</span><br/>
              {Question}</p></a>
              <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="answer">
              {Answer}
              <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <br> {block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
       #<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
        {/block:Answer}

        {Block:IfShowPostCaptions} 
        {block:IndexPage}
        {block:Date} 
            {block:Caption}
                <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
            {/block:Caption}
        {/block:Date} 
        {/block:IndexPage}
        {/Block:IfShowPostCaptions} 


        </div><!-- end #post -->

            {block:PermalinkPage}
            {block:Date}
            <div id="info">
            {block:Caption}
            <div class="caption">
                <div id="background"></div> 
                {Caption}
            </div>{/block:Caption}

            <div class="info_list">
              <div id="background"></div> 
              <ul>
                  {block:NoteCount}
              <li>{NoteCountWithLabel}</li>
                  {/block:NoteCount}
              <li>{DayOfMonthWithZero} {Month} {Year}</li>
                  {block:RebloggedFrom} 
              <li><a href="{ReblogRootURL}" target="_blank">
                  {ReblogRootName}</a></li>
                  {/block:RebloggedFrom} 
                  {block:HighRes} 
              <li><a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" target="_blank">
                  High-Res</a></li>
                  {/block:HighRes}
                  {block:ExternalAudio}
              <li><a href="{ExternalAudioURL}" target="_blank">
                  Download</a></li>
                  {/block:ExternalAudio}
              </ul>
            </div>

            {block:PostNotes} 
            <div class="notes_box">
                <div id="background"></div> 
                {PostNotes}
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            {/block:PostNotes} 
            {/block:Date}
            {/block:PermalinkPage}  

{/block:Posts}
```

Comment: I can't figure out why my code blocks are acting like that. I apologize, but hopefully someone can still help.

Comment: You need to get a different tumblr theme. This has a lot more problems than the tags! Tumblr offers lots of free themes. Themes usually have HTML **and** CSS ;o) Do you have an account on tumblr? If so, just look in footer where it says "themes".

Comment: You could look at this http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/19416/8605 and browse through all the questions tagged with [tag:tags] and [tag:tumblr]. Check [tag:themes] too. Lots of people have the same problem with tumblr themes and tags, including me.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Before seeing them, I managed to figure it out. I've edited my original question since I can't answer my own question due to a lack of rep or something.

Comment: Yayy! I am happy for you. Good job! I should only be so lucky with my own yucky tumblr themes! Come back and visit us again if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

As [answered by OP](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/52831/2)

> I figured it out! Yayyy! I deleted all of the HasTag blocks from the
>   individual post blocks. Instead of adding the HasTags block just
>   before `{/block:Posts}`, I threw it in just before the `<!-- end #post
>   -->` inside the already existing `</div>`.
>
> I also added an `&nbsp` because my tags weren't being spaced apart at
>   all. So now I have the tags underneath the captions and the sources.
>
> It was a lucky shot in the dark, but it worked!
>
> Above is all of the different post blocks like this last one.